# GLut in C - Collision isn't working all the time

Tags: c, linked-list, glut

I'm currently working on a side scroller, my player can shoot, as do the enemies. If I hit an enemy,it should disappear. Unfortunately, it doesn't work all the time. Sometime it does, sometime not. Sometimes, it work perfectly like here :

```
Ennemi 30 =eX:37 - eY:51 
Shot 12=sX:37 - sY:52
====
BOUM
```

and for some reasons, it happens that my shot go trough the enemy like it doesn't exist.

Here's how I detect collision :

```
 void checkCollisionShot(ListShot* list,ListEnnemy* listE){
    if (list == NULL || listE == NULL){
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    Shot *getSh=list->first;
    Ennemy *getEn=listE->first;
    if (list->first!= NULL && listE->first!=NULL)
    {   
        int i,j;

        for(i=0;i<list->nbr;i++){
            int sX=getSh->obj.posi.x;
            int sY=getSh->obj.posi.y;
            for(j=0;i<listE->nbr;i++){
                int eX=getEn->obj.posi.x;
                int eY=getEn->obj.posi.y;
                if(getEn->obj.friend!=getSh->obj.friend){
                    if(sX<eX+3 && sX>=eX){
                        if(sY<eY+3 && sY>=eY){
                            printf("Boum\n");
                            deleteEnnemy(listE,eX,eY);
                            deleteShot(list,sX,sY);
                        }
                    }
                }
                getEn=getEn->next;
            }
            getSh=getSh->next;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm working with simple linked list : One for the shots, another one for the enemies. I'm browsing each element, one by one, and compare each element from a list with the position of the other list.

Is the mistake coming from this function, or does it come from one of the GLut function (-like- the refresh function) ?

Comment: *my shot go trough the enemy* You seem to handle only single coordinates for each shot and each enemy. To be able to "go through" something, wouldn't you need direction or start and end point of a shot?

Comment: `for(j=0;i<listE->nbr;i++)` This should be `for(j=0; j<listE->nbr; j++)`. Why do you use counters at all? You can just check if your pointers are `NULL`?

Comment: Oh god, I was stuck with this for days... Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Gerhardh About the counter, does it really change something ? I know I can do it the other way, but I still need to count the number of elements in my list in others functions, so I also use it there.

Comment: Well, you can't get confused like this while counting if you don't count at all. ;) And it would remove the need to update a counter. What happens if you delete those nodes from the lists? Do you decrement `nbr` fields of both lists? But you will still increment `i` and `j`.

Comment: You call `deleteShot(list,sX,sY);` if you detect a hit. But you still walk through the rest of enemies' list. Is that supposed to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found it ! The declaration of getEn should be reset with every loop. The code look like this now :

```
void checkCollisionShot(ListShot* list,ListEnnemy* listE){
if (list == NULL || listE == NULL)
{
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
Shot *getSh=list->first;    
//GETEN IS NOT HERE ANYMORE<-----------------------------
if (list->first!= NULL && listE->first!=NULL)
{   
    while(getSh!=NULL){
        int sX=getSh->obj.posi.x;
        int sY=getSh->obj.posi.y;
        Ennemy *getEn=listE->first;//<------------------THE DIFFERENCE IS HERE
        while(getEn!=NULL){
            int eX=getEn->obj.posi.x;
            int eY=getEn->obj.posi.y;
            if(getEn->obj.friend!=getSh->obj.friend){
                if(sX<eX+3 && sX>=eX){
                    if(sY<eY+3 && sY>=eY){
                        //exit(0);
                        printf("\n\nBOUM\n");
                        deleteEnnemy(listE,eX,eY);
                        deleteShot(list,sX,sY);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            getEn=getEn->next;
        }
        
        getSh=getSh->next;
    }
}
```

}

For the record, only the first element of the ListShot was compared with every element of the ListEnnemy. Now, every object is compared with each other.